# HttpWebRequest не могу авторизоваться

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

HttpWebRequest не могу авторизоваться. Логин и пароль правильные вот код выполнения https://repl.it/@SierieghaWend/TrustingBitesizedDataset

```
public static void Main (string[] args) {
const String CorrectAuthText = "Login successful";
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://bdonw.ru/index.php?do=login");
var postData = "send_btn=True";
postData += "&login_name=mail@mail.ru";
postData += "&login_password=dragon";
var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{ stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length); }
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
if (responseString.Contains(CorrectAuthText))
{
Console.WriteLine ("successful");
}
else
{
Console.WriteLine ("no successful");
}
```

}

Comment: Где вы в [исходном коде](https://pastebin.com/rfXkPX3b) страницы нашли `Login successful`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ прошу прощения, там этого нету я взял код с сайта

Comment: Отловите запрос, который отправляет сайт к примеру через Fiddler и посмотрите что он точно отправляет (может Cookie, может заголовок или что то еще) и посмотрите ответ. Я мельком глянул и он меня редиректнул на 404 страницу почему то, на которой была кнопка "Выход", но точно не было "Login successful"...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ знал бы я как ловить эти запросы давно бы сделал .

Comment: Поставили программу, запустили, включили отлов, запустили браузер (лучше без расширений), зашли на сайт, вошли под учеткой, выключаете в программе отлов, ищите запрос авторизации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string postCode = "login_name="+Email+"&login_password="+Password+"&login=submit";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(postCode);
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://bdonw.ru");
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.Host = "bdonw.ru";
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "max-age=0");
        req.Headers.Add("Origin", "http://bdonw.ru");
        req.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36 OPR/58.0.3135.107";
        req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8";
        req.Referer = "http://bdonw.ru/";
        req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate");
        req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7");
        req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        using (Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        string result = response.Headers.Get("Set-Cookie");
        var regLogin = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"dle_user_id[^ ]+");
        var regPass = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"dle_password[^ ]+");
        string login = regLogin.Match(result).Value;
        string pass = regPass.Match(result).Value;
        Console.WriteLine("Login {0}\nPassword {1}",login, pass);
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91369/discussion-on-answer-by-sergey-73-httpwebrequest---).

Comment: @Sergey_73 позже отпишу насчет одной штуки по C# я просто 2 недели эти занят был

Comment: @Sergey_73 рума не создается, создай сам пожалуйста

Comment: @Sergey_73 самое интересное мне пишет что у меня должно 20 репутации быть. У тебя есть на примете другие румы, или вконтакте например ?

Comment: Там наверно как то можно пригласить в руму

Comment: @Sergey_73 го суда крч, https://bdonw.ru/index.php?newsid=10&seourl=obsuzhdeniya-oshibok-na-servere

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить свой клиент авторизации *(использую повседневно)*.

P.S. Авторизует на любом сайте, который использует `DataLife Engine`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DleAuthClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (DleEngineWebClient newWorldClient = new DleEngineWebClient(new Uri("http://bdonw.ru/")))
            {
                Console.Write("Enter your login: ");
                string userLogin = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Enter your password: ");
                string userPwd = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Login Result: {0}\nPress Any Key to logout...", newWorldClient.AuthUser(userLogin, userPwd));

                Console.ReadKey(true);

                Console.WriteLine("Logout Result: {0}", newWorldClient.LogoutUser());
            }

            Console.ReadKey(false);
        }

        public struct UserLoginInfo
        {
            private string _userLogin;
            private string _userPassword;

            public UserLoginInfo(string login, string pwd)
            {
                _userLogin = login;
                _userPassword = pwd;
            }

            public HttpContent ZipToSend()
            {
                return new FormUrlEncodedContent(new KeyValuePair<string, string>[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("login_name", _userLogin),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("login_password", _userPassword),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("login", "submit"), 
                });
            }
        }

        class DleEngineWebClient : IDisposable
        {
            private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
            private readonly CookieContainer _cookies;
            private const string cookiesName = "bdo_nw_client.cookie"; // название кукисов

            private readonly string userDocumentsDirectory =
                Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments,
                    Environment.SpecialFolderOption.Create);

            public DleEngineWebClient(Uri siteAddress)
            {
                _cookies = TryLoadCookies();

                HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
                {
                    UseCookies = true,
                    AllowAutoRedirect = true,
                    MaxAutomaticRedirections = 10,
                    CookieContainer = _cookies,
                };

                _httpClient = new HttpClient(clientHandler, true)
                {
                    BaseAddress = siteAddress,
                    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.0D)
                };
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Пытается найти существующие кукисы, и загрузить их.
            /// Если кукисов нет, создадим новые кукисы, и заполним пустыми данными.
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns><seealso cref="CookieContainer"/></returns>
            private CookieContainer TryLoadCookies()
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(userDocumentsDirectory, "BdoNow"));
                string cookiesPath = Path.Combine(userDocumentsDirectory, "BdoNow", cookiesName);
                BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                if (File.Exists(cookiesPath))
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("[{0}] [{1}] Cookies found, try to load...", "INFO", DateTime.Now);
                    using (FileStream fileCookies =
                        File.Open(Path.Combine(cookiesPath), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        return binaryFormatter.Deserialize(fileCookies) as CookieContainer;
                    }
                }

                Debug.WriteLine("[{0}] [{1}] Cookies not found! Create a cookies and write some empty data...",
                    "WARNING", DateTime.Now);
                using (FileStream cookies = File.Create(cookiesPath))
                {
                    binaryFormatter.Serialize(cookies, new CookieContainer());
                    return new CookieContainer();
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Сохраняет кукисы на диск для дальнейшего использования их клиентом.
            /// </summary>
            private void SaveCookies()
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(userDocumentsDirectory, "BdoNow"));
                string cookiesPath = Path.Combine(userDocumentsDirectory, "BdoNow", cookiesName);
                BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                if (File.Exists(cookiesPath))
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("[{0}] [{1}] Saving cookies to disk, before destroy the object...", "INFO", DateTime.Now);
                    using (FileStream fileCookies =
                        File.Open(Path.Combine(cookiesPath), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        binaryFormatter.Serialize(fileCookies, _cookies);
                    }
                }
            }

            public bool LogoutUser()
            {
                return LogoutUserAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }

            public async Task<bool> LogoutUserAsync()
            {
                using (HttpResponseMessage message = await _httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri("/?action=logout", UriKind.Relative)))
                {
                    bool result = message.IsSuccessStatusCode;
                    CookieCollection collection = _cookies.GetCookies(_httpClient.BaseAddress);
                    foreach (Cookie cookie in collection)
                    {
                        if (cookie.Name.Equals("dle_user_id", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ||
                            cookie.Name.Equals("dle_user_password", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            return result && false;
                        }
                    }

                    return result;
                }
            }

            public async Task<bool> AuthUserAsync(string userlogin, string userPwd, CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken))
            {
                using (HttpResponseMessage message = await _httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri("/", UriKind.Relative),
                    new UserLoginInfo(userlogin, userPwd).ZipToSend(), ct))
                {
                    message.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    CookieCollection collection = _cookies.GetCookies(_httpClient.BaseAddress);
                    foreach (Cookie cookie in collection)
                    {
                        if (cookie.Name.Equals("dle_user_id", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ||
                            cookie.Name.Equals("dle_user_password", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            }

            public bool AuthUser(string userlogin, string userPwd)
            {
                return AuthUserAsync(userlogin, userPwd).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }

            private void ReleaseUnmanagedResources()
            {
                _httpClient?.Dispose();
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                ReleaseUnmanagedResources();
                GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            }

            ~DleEngineWebClient()
            {
                SaveCookies();
                ReleaseUnmanagedResources();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ого вот это код) я не дома , посмотрю позже . Спасибо тоже за ответ

Comment: в чем его особенность ?

Comment: Сохранение, загрузка кукисов, т.е. не надо при каждом запуске программы просить пользователя авторизоваться, но, что бы это дело проверить, вам стоит дописать один небольшой метод на подобии `HasLoggedIn()` который бы проверял кукисы на наличие авторизации после их загрузки. Плюс еще в том что он будет работать на любом сайте, который использует движок `DataLife Engine`

Comment: Вы знаите dle достаточно ?

Comment: Думаю вполне достаточно знаний.

Comment: Хорошо , задам вам вопрос мин через 15-20)

Comment: у меня есть база данных, в dle_users я добавил колонку с надписью subscirbe "тип data" , так вот мне нужно сделать что бы пользователь не смог авторизоваться если это число уже прошло

Comment: так вот в dle где то в engine\modules\sitelogin.tpl - этот файл отвечает за авторизацию как я понял

Comment: Если вы хотите получить ответ на интересующий вас вопрос из комментария, вам стоит [задать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) специфичный вопрос, связанный с `php` и `dle`.

Comment: Ок ща задам 1 мин