# Работа с Cookie в HttpClient для парсинга с авторизацией

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода, .net-core, async-await

Мне всегда было интересно, как заставить `HttpClient` работать с куками подобно браузеру, затем сохранять их при выходе из приложения, и продолжить использовать после повторного запуска. И вот, наконец, приспичило, и я сделал.

Реализовал работу `HttpClient` следующим образом:

**Код для инспекции**

```csharp
public static class HttpManager
{
    private static readonly HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.All
    };

    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler)
    {
        DefaultRequestVersion = HttpVersion.Version20
    };

    static HttpManager()
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0");
    }

    // GET
    public static async Task<string> GetPageAsync(string url)
    {
        using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
        return await response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode().Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    // POST
    public static async Task<string> PostFormAsync(string url, Dictionary<string, string> data)
    {
        using HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);
        using HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url) { Content = content };
        using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
        return await response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode().Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    // Загрузить и расшифровать Cookie из файла
    public static async Task LoadCookiesAsync(string filename)
    {
        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            using FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filename);
            byte[] IV = new byte[16];
            fs.Read(IV);
            byte[] protectedKey = new byte[178];
            fs.Read(protectedKey);
            using AesManaged aes = new AesManaged
            {
                Key = ProtectedData.Unprotect(protectedKey, IV, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser),
                IV = IV
            };
            using CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fs, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read, true);
            CookieCollection cookies = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<CookieCollection>(cs);
            foreach (Cookie cookie in cookies)
            {
                // не загружать, если кука заэкспайрилась
                if (!cookie.Expired && (cookie.Expires == DateTime.MinValue || cookie.Expires > DateTime.Now))
                    handler.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);
            }
        }
    }

    // Зашифровать и сохранить Cookie в файл
    public static async Task SaveCookiesAsync(string filename)
    {
        using AesManaged aes = new AesManaged();
        using FileStream fs = File.Create(filename);
        fs.Write(aes.IV);
        fs.Write(ProtectedData.Protect(aes.Key, aes.IV, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser));
        using CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fs, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write, true);
        await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(cs, handler.CookieContainer.GetAllCookies());
    }
}

public static class CookieContainerExtensions
{
    // Забирает все куки из контейнера
    public static CookieCollection GetAllCookies(this CookieContainer container)
    {
        CookieCollection allCookies = new CookieCollection();
        IDictionary domains = (IDictionary)container.GetType()
            .GetRuntimeFields()
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "m_domainTable")
            .GetValue(container);

        foreach (object field in domains.Values)
        {
            IDictionary values = (IDictionary)field.GetType()
                .GetRuntimeFields()
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "m_list")
                .GetValue(field);

            foreach (CookieCollection cookies in values.Values)
            {
                allCookies.Add(cookies);
            }
        }
        return allCookies;
    }
}
```

Куки сериализуются в Json, шифруются с защитой ключа через DPAPI и сохраняются на диск.

---

Воспроизводимый пример, работающий с инспектируемым кодом

**Авторизация на StackOverflow с логином и паролем**

```csharp
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack;
```

```csharp
private const string filename = "cookies.bin";

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{  
    await HttpManager.LoadCookiesAsync(filename);

    string html = await HttpManager.GetPageAsync("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/");
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);
    if (doc.DocumentNode.QuerySelector(".top-bar ol").HasClass("user-logged-out"))
    {
        html = await HttpManager.GetPageAsync("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fru.stackoverflow.com%2f");
        doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);
        string fkey = doc.DocumentNode.QuerySelector("form#login-form input[name=fkey]").Attributes["value"].Value;
        string ssrc = doc.DocumentNode.QuerySelector("form#login-form input[name=ssrc]").Attributes["value"].Value;
        Console.Write("Login: ");
        string login = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Password: ");
        string password = ReadPassword();
        Dictionary<string, string> formData = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "fkey", fkey },
            { "ssrc", ssrc },
            { "email", login },
            { "password", password },
            { "oauth_version", "" },
            { "oauth_server", "" }
        };
        html = await HttpManager.PostFormAsync("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fru.stackoverflow.com%2f", formData);
        doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);
    }

    string user = doc.DocumentNode.QuerySelector(".top-bar ol .my-profile span.v-visible-sr").InnerText;
    Console.WriteLine(user);
    string rep = HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(doc.DocumentNode.QuerySelector(".top-bar ol .my-profile div.-rep").Attributes["title"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(rep);
    string badges = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, doc.DocumentNode.QuerySelectorAll(".top-bar ol .my-profile div.-badges span.v-visible-sr").Select(x => x.InnerText));
    Console.WriteLine(badges);

    await HttpManager.SaveCookiesAsync(filename);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static string ReadPassword()
{
    string password = string.Empty;
    ConsoleKey key;
    do
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
        key = keyInfo.Key;

        if (key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && password.Length > 0)
        {
            Console.Write("\b \b");
            password = password[0..^1];
        }
        else if (!char.IsControl(keyInfo.KeyChar))
        {
            Console.Write("*");
            password += keyInfo.KeyChar;
        }
    } while (key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
    Console.WriteLine();
    return password;
}
```

Вывод в консоль при первом запуске с запросом учетных данных

```
Login: <my_email>@<censored>.ru
Password: ********************
aepot
ваша репутация: 4,904
2 золотых знака
5 серебряных знаков
25 бронзовых знаков
```

Вывод в консоль при повторном запуске приложения, автоматически используются куки для авторизации

```
aepot
ваша репутация: 4,904
2 золотых знака
5 серебряных знаков
25 бронзовых знаков
```

Воспроизводимый пример не нужно инспектировать, я знаю, что в нем не учтены сценарии ошибок при вводе пароля или если вход по паролю не поддерживается учетной записью.

*Кстати! Чтобы работало, нужно, чтобы в параметрах безопасности учетной записи StackExchange был активен способ входа по логину и паролю.*

Посмотрите пожалуйста код класса `HttpManager`, есть ли что улучшить или сделать по-другому? Я раньше не работал с Cookie.

---

**Обновление** - с использованием `BinaryFormatter`

По [совету](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/958900/373567) от **@ヒミコ** попробовал реализацию с использованием `BinaryFormatter`. Тоже работает. Из плюсов - теперь не нужен дополнительный метод для извлечения кук, а `CookieContainer` сохраняется "как есть". Пока не понял, что лучше, но Microsoft [ругает](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) `BinaryFormatter` как небезопасный.

> `BinaryFormatter` is insecure and can't be made secure. For more information, see the [BinaryFormatter security guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide).

```csharp
public static class HttpManager
{
    private static readonly HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.All
    };

    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler)
    {
        DefaultRequestVersion = HttpVersion.Version20
    };

    static HttpManager()
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0");
    }

    public static async Task<string> GetPageAsync(string url)
    {
        using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
        return await response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode().Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    public static async Task<string> PostFormAsync(string url, Dictionary<string, string> data)
    {
        using HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);
        using HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url) { Content = content };
        using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
        return await response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode().Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    public static async Task LoadCookiesAsync(string filename)
    {
        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            using FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filename);
            byte[] IV = new byte[16];
            await fs.ReadAsync(IV);
            byte[] protectedKey = new byte[178];
            await fs.ReadAsync(protectedKey);
            using AesManaged aes = new AesManaged
            {
                Key = ProtectedData.Unprotect(protectedKey, IV, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser),
                IV = IV
            };
            using CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fs, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read, true);
            handler.CookieContainer = new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(cs) as CookieContainer ?? new CookieContainer();
        }
    }

    public static async Task SaveCookiesAsync(string filename)
    {
        using AesManaged aes = new AesManaged();
        using FileStream fs = File.Create(filename);
        await fs.WriteAsync(aes.IV);
        await fs.WriteAsync(ProtectedData.Protect(aes.Key, aes.IV, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser));
        using CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fs, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write, true);
        new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(cs, handler.CookieContainer);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/958755/httpwebrequest-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f/958900?r=SearchResults#958900 давно для dle делал клиент. Может поможет :)

Comment: BinaryFormatter  можно без проблем использовать, если данные остаются в пределах одной машины. То есть для приложения нет опасности использовать свои же данные. А вот получать с его помощью данные извне - опасно: там может оказаться что угодно. И это "что угодно" будет создано в процессе десериализации (конструкторы классов вызваны).

Comment: я тоже решал подобную проблему и написал свой хелпер https://gist.github.com/mt89vein/9c9d7291d42dac0d1598f1a61da3117c. И сериализовал/десериализовал List<Cookie> в json. Чтобы все корректно работало, в HttpClient отключил cookie container, т.к. Handler может быть переиспользован в HttpClientFactory.

Comment: @SultanovShamil свой менеджмент кук хорошо, но зачем, если `HttpClientHandler` прекрасно [справляется](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/CookieHelper.cs) с этой задачей без постороннего вмешательства. Да и сам [`CookieContainer`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Net.Primitives/src/System/Net/CookieContainer.cs) не так прост, как казалось бы.

Comment: Не надо BinaryFormatter: https://github.com/dotnet/designs/pull/141

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight спасибо, я подозревал, что где-то оно должно быть. А что вместо него? Для .NET 5 подозреваю, что `JsonSerializer` справится "из коробки", там вроде сериализацию полей добавили. Или еще что-то есть (кроме XML)?

Comment: @aepot HttpClientHandler справляется, но IHttpClientFactory переиспользует их у себя под капотом и для разных пользователей мне нужен был свой набор кук, а создавать новый HttpClientHandler на каждый запрос - дорого (сокеты не бесконечны и закрываются не быстро), проще куки доставать и закидывать вручную)

Comment: @SultanovShamil странно, выглядит как использование одного браузера одновременно несколькими пользователями под одной учетной записью в системе. Весьма специфичный случай, не популярный. Ну ок, пусть будет так.

Comment: @aepot да, возможно специфичный. У меня кейс когда сервер эмулирует работу юзера в браузере, под аутентификацией на куках. Т.е. нужны изолированые сессии

Comment: @MikhailLazko _Плюс не желание использовать готовое и протестированное решение из нугета_ Перечитал ваш комментарий, вопросов стало еще больше: о каком именно протестированном решении из нугета речь? CefSharp? Selenium? Зачем мне браузер? Почему встроенный в .NET `HttpClient` хуже? Либо я вообще не понял, о чем вы.

Comment: Просто интересно, кому удобно читать новые однострочные using - конструкции? Я до сих пор пишу с фигурными скобками, никак не привыкну

Comment: @AndreiKhotko Мне удобно, избавляет от большой степени вложенности в то время, когда Dispose ожидается в одной и той же точке кода. Когда нужно задиспозить что-нибудь раньше, чем наступит конец кодового блока, я сам пишу по-старому, ну потому-что иначе никак.

Comment: @aepot прощу прощения, перечитал снова тред с коментариямя. похоже я был под кофеинов и потерял нить пока читал) я давно с этим не пересекался но выглядит странным что нет готового решения которое это бы решало из коробки в пару-тройку строк.

Comment: @MikhailLazko ничего, бывает. Но по сути `HttpClient` из коробки и решает, я добавил только чтение и запись кук и базовые настройки.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В итоге решение получилось такое.

Ушел от статики, чтобы решение стало совместимым с IoC паттерном.

```cs
public class HttpManager : IDisposable
{
    private readonly HttpClientHandler handler;
    private readonly HttpClient client;

    public HttpManager(string baseAddress = null)
    {
        handler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.All
        };
        client = new HttpClient(handler)
        {
            DefaultRequestVersion = HttpVersion.Version20
        };
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/111.0");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.ParseAdd("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptLanguage.ParseAdd("en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3");

        if (baseAddress != null)
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
        }
    }

    public async Task<string> GetPageAsync(string url)
    {
        CheckDisposed();
        using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
        return await response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode().Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    public async Task<string> PostFormAsync(string url, Dictionary<string, string> data)
    {
        CheckDisposed();
        using HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);
        using HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url) { Content = content };
        using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
        return await response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode().Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    public async Task LoadCookiesAsync(string fileName)
    {
        CheckDisposed();
        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            using FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fileName);
            byte[] IV = new byte[16];
            await fs.ReadAsync(IV);
            byte[] protectedKey = new byte[178];
            await fs.ReadAsync(protectedKey);
            using AesManaged aes = new AesManaged
            {
                Key = ProtectedData.Unprotect(protectedKey, IV, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser),
                IV = IV
            };
            using CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fs, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read, true);
            CookieCollection cookies = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<CookieCollection>(cs);
            CookieContainer container = new CookieContainer();
            container.Add(cookies);
            handler.CookieContainer = container;
        }
    }

    public async Task SaveCookiesAsync(string fileName)
    {
        CheckDisposed();
        using AesManaged aes = new AesManaged();
        using FileStream fs = File.Create(fileName);
        await fs.WriteAsync(aes.IV);
        await fs.WriteAsync(ProtectedData.Protect(aes.Key, aes.IV, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser));
        using CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fs, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write, true);
        await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(cs, handler.CookieContainer.GetAllCookies());
    }

    private bool disposed;

    private void CheckDisposed()
    {
        if (disposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(nameof(HttpManager));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        CheckDisposed();
        if (disposing)
            client.Dispose();
        disposed = true;
    }

    ~HttpManager() => Dispose(false);
}
```

Уйти от рефлексии не удалось, вот метод для извлечения кук:

```cs
public static class CookieContainerExtensions
{
    public static CookieCollection GetAllCookies(this CookieContainer container)
    {
        CookieCollection allCookies = new CookieCollection();
        Hashtable domainTable = (Hashtable)container.GetType()
            .GetRuntimeFields()
            .First(x => x.Name == "m_domainTable")
            .GetValue(container);

        FieldInfo pathListField = null;
        foreach (object domain in domainTable.Values)
        {
            SortedList pathList = (SortedList)(pathListField ??= domain.GetType()
                .GetRuntimeFields()
                .First(x => x.Name == "m_list"))
                .GetValue(domain);

            foreach (CookieCollection cookies in pathList.GetValueList())
                allCookies.Add(cookies);
        }
        return allCookies;
    }
}
```

Использование

```cs
string fileName = "cookies.bin";
using HttpManager manager = new HttpManager("https://<адрес сайта>/");
await manager.LoadCookiesAsync(fileName);
string html = await manager.GetPageAsync("/admin");
//...

await manager.SaveCookiesAsync(filename);
Console.WriteLine("Done.");
```

---

#### Новинка в .NET 6

В .NET 6 добавлен метод `CookieContainer` - [GetAllCookies()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotNet/api/system.net.cookiecontainer.getallcookies?view=net-6.0).

Comment: подходят ли для Web Assembly данные куки ? как можно разобраться, чтоб интегрировать ? Благодарю

Comment: @Dev18 вообще это клиентский код, а Wasm это само по себе в браузере. Зачем эмуляция поведения браузера, когда вы и так в настоящем браузере находитесь? Напишите нужных JS функций и интегрируйтесь с ними.