# c# HttpClient прикрепить картинку при отправке POST запроса

Tags: c#, post, httpclient

Искал пробовал\пробовал информацию в интернете, получал одни ошибки.
Нужно отправить **POST** запрос с параметрами, одним из параметров передать картинку.

**Мой код:**

```cs
var baseAddress = new Uri("domain.com");

using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
{
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("avtoriz_user_adv", "off"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("name_adv",  Title),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("text_adv", Msg),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key_words", ""),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("time_adv", "month"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("img_adv[]", "(binary)"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("imagesValue", "ТУТ ДОЛЖНА БЫТЬ КАРТИНКА.JPG"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("captcha", getCaptcha(convertIMG.Base64ToImage(photobytes))),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("PHPSESSID", PHPSESSID),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("add_maps", "off"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("longitude", "0"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("latitude", "0"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("is_new_adv", "alkdt"),
    });
    var result = await client.PostAsync("uploadfile_new.php", content);
    result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    return await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Тут должно быть изображение

```cs
new KeyValuePair<string, string>("imagesValue", "ТУТ ДОЛЖНА БЫТЬ КАРТИНКА.JPG"),
```

Изображение нужно передавать как `byte[]`?
`KeyValuePair` принимает только `string`.

В примерах что находил изображение передавали на сервер без дополнительных параметров.
Как это сделать?
Спасибо:)

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно на запрос, который отправляет браузер серверу, а именно какого он типа.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ,
Request Method: POST

Comment: это не то, смотрите что у вас в ContentType и чему равен этот `imagesValue`

Comment: Не стоит создавать новый `HttpClient` на каждый запрос, это может привести к нехватке сокетов. Вместо этого рекомендуется создать один экземпляр `HttpClient` и переиспользовать его на протяжении всей работы приложения ([документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8#examples), [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1178026/373567)).

Comment: По поводу самого вопроса - без оригинального запроса, отправляемого браузером, который вы хотите воспроизвести, понять, как оно должно быть, не возможно. Возможна сама картинка энкодится в Base64.

Comment: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
imagesValue: ca8bfd27c2dd46399d03f6b069f62f7c.jpg
Вроде понял, сначала GET методом загружается картинка https://rudos.ru/upload_adv/uploads/small_img/ca8bfd27c2dd46399d03f6b069f62f7c.jpg
Затем в imagesValue передаётся ca8bfd27c2dd46399d03f6b069f62f7c.jpg

Comment: Это похоже на имя файла, а не на картинку. Да, возможно так и есть.

Comment: @aepot, спасибо за совет:)
Запрос к URL: https://rudos.ru/moduls/doska/include/uploadfile_new.php

Comment: Только не понимаю откуда берётся "ca8bfd27c2dd46399d03f6b069f62f7c", картинка имеет имя 1.jpg

Comment: Вероятно, когда вы ее заливаете на сервер POST запросом, сервер вам как раз возвращает имя файла.

Comment: Так и оказалось, спасибо за помощь:)