# Как авторизоваться на сайте без сторонних библиотек на C#?

Tags: c#, веб-программирование

Вообщем, перерыл я горы информации в интернете, но ничего толкового, что полностью бы объясняло мою проблему, не нашел.
Моя цель - авторизоваться на сайте https://passport.meta.ua/login/
Если переходить более детально к вопросу, то мне не понятно:

1. Что такое HTTP-Headers, т.е что такое HTTP-заголовки?
2. Как авторизовываться, используя файлы cookie?
3. Какие данные обязательно отправлять сайту? ( зайдя в F12 в гугле я увидел Referer, Accept, User-Agent, Content-Lenght, Content-type и прочие интересные и не очень вещи, которые сбили меня с толку: неужели мне это всё надо что ли отправлять? )
4. Ну и самое главное: как всё-таки авторизоваться?
   Буду очень рад, если вы приведете куски кода, а также разжуёте всё в самых мельчайших деталях. Вовек вас не забуду тогда!

Comment: Если просто забить в гугл `Что такое HTTP-Headers`, то получите пачку ссылок с объяснениями. Расскажите, какие конкретно проблемы у вас и как вы сами их пытались решить.

Comment: [Пример с использованием кук](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1178026/373567), [HTTP](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP)

Comment: `Как авторизоваться на сайте` - не как, ибо там 
ReCaptcha.

Comment: @tym32167 Проблема такова: мне надо авторизоваться на сайте, не используя сторонние библиотеки, как, например, selenium. Пытался их решить, смотря исходники подобных программ на github, но там везде используют библиотеку selenium или ей подобную. Смотрел видео, читал статьи, но, к сожалению, ничего не понял. Убил на это порядком две недели, после чего обратился сюда.