# Бесконечное обновление страницы. C# Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

Дополнение: Такое происходит только на этапе проверки браузера (Checking your browser before accessing....)

Хочу спарсить сайт, но на нём стоит защита `CloudFlare`, из-за него происходит бесконечная перезагрузка страницы. Хотя если заходить вручную в браузер и вбивать сайт, то всё работает. Пробовал `Selenium.Chrome` и `Selenium.Chrome` - ничего не работает. Попробовал `Selenium.IE` пустило на сайт, но мой код почему-то с ним не работает. В чём может быть проблема?

Код который использую:

```
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Url = ("https://рандомный-сайт-с-защитой-сloudfire.рф/");
```

Comment: `СloudFlare` - не защита, а лишь ограничение, которое обходится в два клика. Поэтому у меня к вам вопрос, который я вроде задавал: зачем вам селениум?

Comment: А вроде не задавали. А так автоматизировать работу с сайтом.

Comment: А вроде задавал, ну да ладно. Чем вам простые POST/GET запросы не угодили? Селениум не для этих целей создан, его задача - тестирование сайта, а для автоматизации, во многих случаях, он хм, как съездить на танке в магазин через дорогу за хлебом, попросту избыточен.

Comment: Ну вот мне хочется съездить на танке в магазин, смотря на дороги))) А так работа с Selenium кажется проще. Т.к на сайте нужна авторизация

Comment: То, что вы видите, это UI, который предназначен для нас с вами, людей, чтоб нам было интуитивно удобно и понятно. Но каждая кнопочка, каждое действие, это отправка POST/GET запроса на сервер. К примеру, вот я пишу вам комментарий, это POST запрос на определенный адрес с телом, которое содержит простой `string`. И вот давайте подумаем, вы пишете интерфейс, для интерфейса, чтобы автоматизировать работу с сайтом, не кажется тут что-то лишнее?) А по поводу "легче" - ну, не сказал бы.

Comment: Я потом хочу скрыть интерфейс. Как всё сделаю.

Comment: Это не отменяет того факта, что вы делаете программу, которая запускает браузер, который автоматизирует действия пользователя в UI (кликает по кнопочкам за вас). Зачем вам этот лишний слой? Делайте сразу запрос на сайте, да и радуйтесь жизнью.

Comment: POST/GET запросы надо правильно формировать. Пробовал отправить любой запрос на сайт программой Postman с этой защитой, но мне пришёл ответ странички защиты, о том что браузер проверяется.

Comment: Дайте мне любой сайт с этой защитой.

Comment: Даже не знаю какой. А если я отправлю сайт который пытаюсь спарсить, то мне тапком по голове прилетит.

Comment: Неважно, что вы скроете интерфейс. Почитайте как в статьях пишут про то, как много ваши танки на базе селениум жрут ресурсов сервера и приходится фермы сооружать. Впрочем, если вас это устраивает...

Comment: На то и есть танки, чтобы быть танками.

Comment: Открыл свой любимый сайт политических новостей в хром.драйвер84, попробовал открыть пару рандомных сайтов, перечисленных в википедии, как "такие крупные сайты как" - всё работает. Проблема с конкретным сайтом и похоже, не зависит от Cloudfire.

Comment: Использовую драйвер к версии 86

Comment: [С авторизацией и без браузера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1178026/373567)

Comment: А CloudFlare не будет блокировать?

Comment: Я не как таблетку от всех болезней скинул, а как "вот еще такое есть". Вы можете проверить. Если даже и будет блокировать, блокировку скорее всего можно обойти, правильно построив запросы. Поисковые боты же как-то обходят. [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32426051/12888024) кстати доказательство того, если проблема есть, скорее ввсего она уже решена. Код там правда старый, но суть та же, и это легко прикручивается к `HttpClient`.

Comment: @aepot Есть уже давно готовые решения, например [CloudflareSolverRe](https://github.com/RyuzakiH/CloudflareSolverRe) или более старый [CloudFlareUtilities](https://github.com/elcattivo/CloudFlareUtilities). А так, я сам писал обход для CF, довольно просто, да и кода можно меньше написать (правда это было года 4 назад), но, автор хочет селениум))

Comment: @EvgeniyZ AngleSharp вроде еще скрипты умеет запускать, но я не пробовал. А автор хочет просто результат, который осязаем, чтобы как можно меньше трудиться. Производительность, потребление памяти, и оптимальность решения здесь никого не интересует. И я даже понимаю это, поэтому показал пару осязаемых вариантов, дело за автором.