# Как подружить ChromiumWebBrowser + IPv6?

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

Никак не удается сделать так, чтобы виртуальный браузер CEF работал с ServicePoint.

Можно ли в эмуляторе подключит ServicePoint или как-то по другому указывать сетевой интерфейс?

Если загрузить через CEF url yandex.ru/internet, то там показывает и Ipv4, а должно быть пусто.

Comment: А почему бы не сразу грузить страницы через `HttpClient` и потом парсить, скажем с помощью `HtmlAgilityPack` или `AngleSharp`? [Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1178026/373567). Браузер - штука медленная и тяжелая, оно точно вам надо, и по-другому никак?

Comment: Нужен именно CEF, другие вариант то работают, никаких проблем, но нужно грузить страницы, визуально показывать и все через ipv6, не консольно. Если загрузить через CEF url https://yandex.ru/internet/, то там показывает и Ipv4, а должно быть пусто.

Comment: В таком случае, ваш вопрос не понятен, отредактируйте его так, чтобы он был сфокусирован на одной проблеме. Попутно, показывать и парсить - разные задачи, и их можно решать параллельно разными средствами.

Comment: Насчет CEF не знаю, но `HttpClient` кажись может.

Comment: Может с сервис понитами, там нет проблем, а вот CEF проблема