# Как загрузить данные профиля в Headless chromedriver Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

Я использую Selenium + C# + chromedriver с опцией **--headless**.

Для входа в учетные записи я использую профили хрома, где предварительно была проделана процедура логина.
Это все отлично работает, но проблема в том, что только в режиме с головой. *Как только включаю headless нужно логиниться заново* (Понял по скриншотам).
Как я понимаю, браузер в режиме --headless не получает данные профиля.
Пытался разобраться в проблеме при помощи гугла, но безуспешно, наткнулся только на аргументы принудительного отключения кэширования и создания куки.

Помогите разобраться с проблемой, буду безмерно благодарен)

Comment: Если вам нужно просто парсить с авторизацией, но не отображать страницу, то вам в принципе [не нужен браузер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1178026/373567).

Comment: Я не занимаюсь парсингом. В двух словах, запуская браузер, я должен быть авторизован в нужном сервисе. Авторизовавшись однажды я могу использовать обычный хромдрайвер и все работает успешно. Вопрос в том, почему прекращает работу с флагом --headless

Comment: Неужели по назначению Selenium используете? :) То есть для автотестов, сейчас редко такие случаи в вопросах попадаются. Зачем вам тогда headless? А если и нужен, то в чем тогда проблема авторизоваться на сайте каждый раз заново? Заодно будете уверены в том, что авторизация точно не поломалась. Как я понял, гуглы сделали это дял безопасности. Представьте, приедет к вам вирус, который запустит в фоне хром и будет под вашим аккаунтом всякое вытворять, а вы даже этого не заметите. Но это всего-лишь гипотеза.

Comment: По назначению? не дай Бог))) Использую для автоматизации. Авторизация не проблема, только если не установлена каптча) Да и вопрос скорее исследовательского характера, авторизация здесь лишь как пример. Уверен, можно найти еще 10000 задач, где понадобятся данные профиля в хедлесе.  Достаточно давно использую селениум, но только сейчас столкнулся с этой проблемой.  Хотелось бы узнать почему так и как это исправить.

Comment: Ну я выше написал, почему, и скорее всего никак. Ибо была бы дыра в безопасности.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Много времени потратил на решение задачи. Конкретно ответа почему в хедлесе не подтягиваются данные профиля так и не нашел.

Обошел проблему с помощью получения куков для нужных профилей с помощью

```
driver.Manage().Cookies.AddCookie(new Cookie("Coockie_name", "value"));
driver.Manage().Cookies.GetCookieNamed("name");
```

Может кому пригодится