# HttpClient.SendAsync перенаправление в Net.Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, httpclient

Использовал `HttpClient.SendAsync` в `Net.Framework` и не получал исключений при встрече с перенаправлением `StatusCode 302`

А попробовал перейти на `Net.Core` и `HttpClient.SendAsync` стал выдавать исключение

Как сделать так, чтобы перенаправление проходило и на `Net.Core` ?

- Хочу ещё отметить что перенаправление там идёт с `https` на `http`

Попробовал, но не помогло:

```
    static readonly HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler() { AllowAutoRedirect = true };
    static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что на `Net.Core` мне придётся самому отлавливать `StatusCode`-ы и в случае перенаправления, ловить `Location` и самому перенаправляться ?

Или всё таки можно установить какое то свойство и чтобы это не являлось исключением.

**UPD 1:**

В `Net.Framework` перенаправление проходит само по себе, т.е. получаю html тело страницы на которую произошло перенаправление.

А `Net.Core` выдаёт исключение.

```
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

**UPD 2 - Исключение:**

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: "Response status code does not indicate success: 302 (Found)."
```

**UPD 3 - Использование целиком**

```
    static readonly HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler() { AllowAutoRedirect = true };
    static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);

    private async Task<string[]> GetHtmlPageAsync(string param1, string url)
    {

        string[] otvet = new string[2];

        using HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
        request.Headers.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36");

        request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("param1", param1),
            // и другие
        });

        using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        int responseHttpStatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;

        otvet[0] = responseHttpStatusCode.ToString();
        otvet[1] = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return otvet;

    }
```

Comment: При 302 не должно быть исключения, покажите код метода и какое именно исключение возникает, покажите его текст. `с https на http` - быть может наоборот? Ну меня на .NET Core все редиректы работают как надо без дополнительных настроек.

Comment: Не задаете ли вы случаем заголовки `Host` или `Origin` при запросе? Если да, то уберите, и все заработает.

Comment: @aepot да - задавал, спасибо! попробую.

Comment: @aepot стоп, а я ведь и на Net.Framework тоже их задавал...

Comment: В .NET Framework `HttpClient` использует другой (старый) транспорт, он может логически по-другому реагировать на эти заголовки.

Comment: [Документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1) - почитайте.

Comment: @aepot исключил все заголовки кроме User-Agent и всё равно на 302 всё стопится

Comment: Я работаю с `HttpClient` [вот так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1217351/373567), редиректы отрабатывают как надо.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23801

Comment: Попробуйте убрать `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`, просто `SendAsync(request)`. Я если честно не уверен, оно влияет как-то или нет.

Comment: Судя по всему проблема именно с перенаправлением с https на http и на .net core оно запрещено. В качестве workaround предлагают отключить авторедирект и руками обрабатывать заголовок 302

Comment: @Grundy да, это не адекватный редирект, и его не должно существовать в природе. Тогда автору рекомендую либо отрабатывать вручную это перенаправление, либо обращаться сразу к HTTP. Авторедирект можно не отключать, так как исключение бросает именно `EnsureSuccessStatusCode()`, то есть всю работу можно провести до него.

Comment: Но заголовок `Host` все равно не надо задавать, при редиректе на другой сайт будет ошибка установки SSL соединения в этом случае при использовании HTTPS.

Comment: [Вот здесь](https://long2know.com/2016/07/capturing-redirects-with-httpclient/) более-менее вменяемый пример как отработать редирект вручную.