# C# Повторное открытие формы с CefSharp

Tags: c#, winforms, form, cefsharp

Есть код:

```cs
MainBot mainBot = new MainBot();
mainBot.IdBot = "hm";
mainBot.Url = "https://www.home-style.shop/";
mainBot.Proxy = "";
mainBot.IdBtn = "";
mainBot.TimeBtnClick = 1000;
mainBot.TimeReturn = 5000;
mainBot.Show();
```

Он открывате форму как бы с браузером (использование CefSharp библиотеки),
после закрывает её через время указаное в TimeReturn -> `this.Close();`
При повторном открытии формы через кнопку пишет ->

```
CEF can only be initialized once per process.  
This is a limitation of the underlying CEF/Chromium framework.
You can change many (not all) settings at runtime through RequestContext.SetPreference. See
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#request-context-browser-isolation Use Cef.IsInitialized to guard against this exception. 
If you are seeing this unexpectedly then you are likely calling Cef.Initialize after you've created an instance of ChromiumWebBrowser, 
it must be before the first instance is created.
```

Инцилизацию можно проводить один раз.
Поэтому я добавил в форму **FormClosing** и вписал `Cef.Shutdown();`
Ошибка инцилизации исправилась, но теперь при повторным открытии форма не  открываться,
а форма из который открывали просто зависает и закрывается.
Подскажите пожалуйста что делать

Код фрагмента из форма которая вызывает форму с Cef

```cs
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainBot mainBot = new MainBot();
    mainBot.IdBot = "hm";
    mainBot.Url = "https://www.home-style.shop/";
    mainBot.Proxy = "";
    mainBot.IdBtn = "";
    mainBot.TimeBtnClick = 1000;
    mainBot.TimeReturn = 5000;
    mainBot.Show();
}
```

Полный код формы браузера:

```cs
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BrowserBotVisitor
{
    public partial class MainBot : Form
    {
        public ChromiumWebBrowser chromiumBrowser;

        public string IdBot { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Proxy { get; set; }
        public string IdBtn { get; set; }
        public int TimeBtnClick { get; set; }
        public int TimeReturn { get; set; }

        public MainBot()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MainBot_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TheClose.Interval = TimeReturn;
            ClickBtn.Interval = TimeBtnClick;
            TheClose.Start();
            ClickBtn.Start();

            CefSettings cfsettigns = new CefSettings();

            if(Proxy.Length > 0)
              cfsettigns.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-server", Proxy);

            string title = "TabPage " + (tabControl.TabCount + 1).ToString();
            TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(title);
            tabControl.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);

            Cef.Initialize(cfsettigns);
            txtUrl.Text = Url;
            chromiumBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(txtUrl.Text);
            chromiumBrowser.Parent = tabControl.SelectedTab;
            chromiumBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            chromiumBrowser.AddressChanged += Chrome_AddresChanged;
            chromiumBrowser.TitleChanged += ChromiumBrowser_TitleChanged;
            OnBeforeClose(chromiumBrowser);
        }

        public virtual void OnBeforeClose(IWebBrowser browser)
        {
            // ничего не делать
        }

        private void ChromiumBrowser_TitleChanged(object sender, 
           TitleChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
            {
                tabControl.SelectedTab.Text = e.Title;
            }));
        }

        private void Chrome_AddresChanged(object sender, AddressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
            {
                txtUrl.Text = e.Address;
            }));
        }
        void BtnClick()
        {
            if (IdBtn.Length > 0)
            {
                ClickBtn.Stop();
                string BtnID = "document.querySelector('" + IdBtn + "').click()";
                chromiumBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync(BtnID);
            }
        }

        private void ClickBtn_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BtnClick();
        }

        private void TheClose_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void MainBot_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Cef.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В главной форме нужно иметь единожды инициализированный экземп. `Cef` (приватное поле например) и при открытии второй формы передавать ссылку на этот экземпляр через параметр в конструкторе второй формы.

Comment: @Bulson но ведь ничего не поменяется

Comment: Почему? Всегда один и тот же экземляр Cef.

Comment: @Bulson У меня же по логике одно экзем Cef просто форма с ним вызваеться как новая копия, а перед открытием новой закрываеться старая и по логике у мнея каждый раз новый Cef а старый как бы стираеться, но проблема в том что даже при удалении закрытие форма без Cef.Shutdown(); он пишет что нельзя инцелизировать ещё один экземп. Cef. А если с Cef.Shutdown(); то просто при создании второй копии формы ничго не просходит и программа вылетает без ошибки

Comment: Нужно больше кода.

Comment: соглашусь с @aepot

Comment: @aepot добавил больше кода

Comment: @Bulson добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Движок браузера `Cef` нужно инициализировать и завершать только один раз за все время работы приложения.

```cs
private void MainBot_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TheClose.Interval = TimeReturn;
    ClickBtn.Interval = TimeBtnClick;
    TheClose.Start();
    ClickBtn.Start();

    if (!Cef.IsInitialized)
    {
        CefSettings cfsettigns = new CefSettings();
        if(Proxy.Length > 0)
            cfsettigns.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-server", Proxy);
        Cef.Initialize(cfsettigns);
    }

    string title = "TabPage " + (tabControl.TabCount + 1).ToString();
    TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(title);
    tabControl.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
            
    txtUrl.Text = Url;
    chromiumBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(txtUrl.Text);
    chromiumBrowser.Parent = tabControl.SelectedTab;
    chromiumBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    chromiumBrowser.AddressChanged += Chrome_AddresChanged;
    chromiumBrowser.TitleChanged += ChromiumBrowser_TitleChanged;
    OnBeforeClose(chromiumBrowser); // это можно убрать, так как вызываемый метод пуст
}
```

Там где у вас `Cef.Shutdown()` сейчас напишите вот так

```cs
private void MainBot_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    chromiumBrowser.Dispose();
}
```

Это высвободит ресурсы, потребляемые уже ненужным окном браузера.

А `Cef.Shutdown()` вынесите в `FormClosing` главной формы, то есть оно должно  выполниться только в случае закрытия всего приложения, а не дочернего окна.

Причем напишите это так (пусть это будет `MainForm`)

```cs
private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (Cef.IsInitialized)
        Cef.Shutdown();
}
```

*Кстати, парсить сайты можно вообще без браузера, [даже с авторизацией](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1217351/373567). Браузер нужен только в особо специфичных случаях, в основном когда нужно показать веб-страницу пользователю. Если показывать не надо, то и браузер в целом не нужен.*

Comment: А если я буду изменять проски у меня будет менятся он ? или же нет ?

Comment: Он как раз не меняется ведь Cef settings уже инициализирован, в этом и есть главная проблема

Comment: @danrom11 на этот вопрос у меня нет ответа, я никогда не работал с **Cef**, но наверное это [как-то так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36106994/12888024) делается.

Comment: Огромное тебе спасибо всё заработало, воспользовался ещё тем что ты указал выше(смена прокси во время работы)