# c# WPF Как обращаться к WebBrowser из другого потока?

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser

Есть форма, на форме расположен WebBrowser.
С основного потока создаю несколько дополнительных:

```
    IProgress<string> progress;
    SemaphoreSlim semaphore;
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        progress = new Progress<string>(s => WorkLog.Text += s + Environment.NewLine);
        try
        { 
            ObservableCollection<TaskTable> _devices = new ObservableCollection<TaskTable>();
             
            int maxConcurrency = 10; // сколько одновременно может работать потоков
            using ( semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxConcurrency))
            {
                List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

                for (int i = 0; i < MyCollection.Count; i++)
                {
                    int id = i;
                    await semaphore.WaitAsync(); // ждать, если максимальное количество уже работает, пока потоков не станет меньше

                    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
                  {
                     
                    AddPost(progress, id, semaphore);
                  }));

                }
                await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // ждать завершения всех
            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            progress.Report("Ошибка в Button_Click");
        }

    }
```

Мне нужно что бы  из метода **AddPost(progress, id, semaphore);** можно было обратиться к WebBrowser, передать ему URL страницы которую нужно загрузить и получить HTML ответ.

Пробавал передавать методу AddPost WebBrowser:

```
AddPost(progress, id, semaphore, WebBrowser1);
```

И далее в AddPost обращаться к браузеру:

```
 WebBrowser1.Navigate(Url);
```

Но форма все равно зависает.

Не использую httpClient потому что перед отправкой запроса нужна предварительная авторизация, для меня реализовать оказалось слишком сложно.

Как нескольким потокам можна обращаться к WebBrowser и получать HTML загруженой страницы?

Спасибо

Comment: `WebBrowser` это ерунда, которая способна лишь отобразить простенькую страничку. Авторизация, это запросы, cookie, ключи и все в этом духе. Хотите браузер - используйте полноценные движки, но мой вам совет, попробуйте проанализировать сайт, понять, как он работает, что отправляет, а затем попробуйте это все отправить простыми запросами, в большинстве случаев этого достаточно!

Comment: Возможно дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418461/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Мне и нужно всего навсего отобразить страницу. Это instagram, мне нужно получить список постов в аккаунте, получить их можно отправив запрос с параметром ?__a=1, пример: https://www.instagram.com/zuck/?__a=1 Но instagram через раз просит предварительно авторизироваться, а с их авторизацией разобраться не получилось

Comment: `нужна предварительная авторизация` https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1217351/373567

Comment: `WebBrowser` - это Internet Explorer 11, он несовместим с интернетом, вы просто пока еще этого не поняли. Используйте `WebView2` или `CefSharp`, если уж вам так нужен браузер и без него никак.

Comment: А если в лоб вашу проблему решать (которая на самом деле - самый настоящий дедлок), то можно вот такое испробовать `Dispatcher.Invoke(() => WebBrowser1.Navigate(Url));`