# Как десериализовать json с сайта в c#?

Tags: c#, json, parse

Есть json код расположенный на сайте в теге `<script>`, как можно его спарсить, десериализовать и использовать в c# коде?

Comment: 1. Выдергиваете данные из тега `<script>` регексом, `AngleSharp` или чем угодно. 2. Создаете соответствующий структуре вашего джисона класс обертку(можно создать классы автоматом, прям из VS спец вставка в меню) 3. Используя, например Newtonsoft и ваш класс-обертку дессерилизуете джисон. Все

Comment: Есть конкретная ссылка на сайт? И какой именно json надо оттуда достать.

Comment: А чего json код делает в теге скрипт? ;)

Comment: Так сервер отвечает на post и размещает эти данные на странице(через гет не получить их)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Текущее решение: Отправляю post:

```cs
using (Stream dataStream = Response.GetRequestStream())
{
    dataStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Получаю ответ:

```cs
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)Response.GetResponse())
using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

получаю из ответа нужный тег(`AngleSharp`'ом через селектор):

```cs
var parser = new HtmlParser();
var doc = parser.ParseDocument(html);
var resStr = doc.QuerySelector(selector).TextContent;
```

обрезаю(название функции JS и ";") полученную строку `String.Substring()`'ом, полученную строку отправляю в десериализатор и готово)*:

```cs
return (List<T>)JsonSerializer.Deserialize(str, typeof(List<T>));
```

P.S. Уверен, что можно сделать и лучше, если знаете как, напишите

Comment: пара советов 1) `HttpWebRequest` устарел, используйте `HttpClient` 2) `return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<T>>(str)` использование дженерик методов улучшает читабельность кода 3) весь ваш код синхронный, если он будет выполняться в UI потоке, приложение будет подвисать на время запроса

Comment: `string html = await client.GetStringAsync(url)` - отправить GET и получить ответ от сервера с помощью `HttpClient` можно так.

Comment: [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1217351/373567) - смотрите методы `GetPageAsync` и `PostFormAsync`, а можете просто взять этот класс и использовать как готовое решение для работы с сетью.