# Добавление куки листа WebView2

Tags: c#, winforms, webview

Как добавить коллекцию куки в `WebView2` на основе WinForms?

Как делал раньше:
Прогонял список куки через `foreach` , если сайт подходит , добавлял в контейнер, сейчас так не хочет

`webView.CoreWebView2.CookieManager.CreateCookie()` <-- требует формат `string, string, string, string` и больше никак

`webView.CoreWebView2.CookieManager.CreateCookieWithSystemNetCookie(Cookie cookie)` <-- позволяет добавить только 1 куку

`webView.CoreWebView2.CookieManager.AddOrUpdateCookie(CoreWebView2Cookie cookie)` <-- Не дается

```
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2;
     using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;
     using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms;
     using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.Raw;

    List<string> cookie = new List<string>();

    private async void guna2Button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
        string uri = @"https://trovo.live";
        webView.CoreWebView2.CookieManager.AddOrUpdateCookie(AddCookie());
        webView.CoreWebView2.Navigate(uri);
    }
    private CoreWebView2Cookie AddCookie()
    {
        CoreWebView2Cookie core = new CoreWebView2Cookie();
        foreach(string cook in cookie)
        if(cook.Contains("trovo"))
            {
                string[] str = cook.Split(new char[] { '\t' });
                core.Domain = str[0];
                //и т.д.
            }
        return core;
    }
```

Долнение #1

```
 private async void guna2Button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
        webView.CoreWebView2Ready += WebView2_CoreWebView2Ready;
    }
    private void WebView2_CoreWebView2Ready(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var coreWebView2 = webView.CoreWebView2;
            coreWebView2.AddWebResourceRequestedFilter("url", CoreWebView2WebResourceContext.All);
            coreWebView2.WebResourceRequested += CoreWebView2_WebResourceRequested;

            coreWebView2.Navigate("url");
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, exception.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }

    private void CoreWebView2_WebResourceRequested(object sender, CoreWebView2WebResourceRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Request.Headers.SetHeader("name", "value");
    }
```

Comment: А зачем вам вообще браузер? Чисто для кук? Или надо страничку пользователю обязательно показать? Быть может [такая штука](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1178026/373567) подойдёт?

Comment: @aepot такая штука есть. Надо именно страничку показать, в этом то и сложность, причем показать ее надо будучи авторизованным. Т.е. зайти через куки

Comment: А если [так](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1983408d-f9d9-44fd-a0c3-88b30d757644/how-to-set-cookies-to-webview2-control-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral)?

Comment: @aepot Сходу выдает ошибку

Ошибка CS1061 "WebView2" не содержит определения "CoreWebView2Ready", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "CoreWebView2Ready", принимающий тип "WebView2" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку). 

Это под WPF подозреваю. Юзинг поставил , даже в документашке порылся , ничего не нашел толкового. Она говорит что все верно, но нет

Comment: Там не в WPF дело, а в том, что WW2 еще в разработке и событие могли переназвать по-другому в одной из версий, ищите что-то похожее.

Comment: @aepot Нет. Не подходит. Просто не добавляется и все