# Добавление заголовков в CefSharp

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Пытаюсь запулить куки через headers.Через куки никак не получается. Как правильно сделать, чтобы страница открывалась с моими заголовками?

```
private void DataGridView3_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
            string sitename == "stackoverflow.com";
            Input(sitename);
            chromiumWebBrowser1.Load("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/");
        }
    }
private void Input(string sitename)
    {
        Request req = new Request();
        foreach(string str in cookie) // List<string> с куками в формате NetScape
            if(str.Contains(sitename))
            {
                string[] tok = str.Split(new char[] { '\t' });
                req.Headers.Add(tok[5],tok[6]); //name и value
            }
    }
```

Comment: Что вы видите [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie)? Похоже это на ваш результат? Также я советую вам разобраться всеж с проблемой, а не бежать от нее, делая костыли. Ну и также, вы уверены вообще, что вам нужен браузер? Большинство задач по автоматизации решаются без него.

Comment: [Просто оставлю это здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1217351/373567)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да , нужен именно браузер. Нет, ваша ссылка не подходит. Нужно под CefSharp. Там как то можно работать с куками , но как я разобраться не могу уже неделю. Куча способов перепробовал

Comment: @aepot Проблема с CefSharp

Comment: @AppleOne А теперь еще раз открываем мою ссылку и смотрим формат заголовка, видим там `Cookie: name=value; name2=value2; name3=value3`, вот вы решили допустим пойти костыльным способом, добавляя заголовки, вот тут у вас `req.Headers.Add(tok[5],tok[6]);` какой формат? Похож ли он на тот, что я вам показал? Есть ли там хотяб `Cookie:` в начале? Так что, точно уверены, что "не подходит"?

Comment: "- У меня не работает! - Что не работает? - Ничего не работает! - А надо что? - А надо, чтобы работало!" **Вопрос подлежит закрытию**, так как совершенно непонятно, что содержит поле `cookie`. Вы показываете код, который работает с непонятно чем, выдает непонятно какой результат, а только сообщаете что он не работает. Окей, мы все поняли, что он не работает. А как вы это поняли? Экран потемнел там, звуки лишние появились, как? Или это викторина, и надо угадать? Так тогда прямо и скажите, что "угадайте, что у меня сломалось?".