# Загрузка куки в CefSharp из CookieContainer

Tags: c#, cookie, cefsharp

Я сохраняю куки файлы (из RestClient) с помощью:

```
client.CookieContainer.GetCookieHeader(new Uri("url"));
var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
var wstr = File.OpenWrite(path + "/Cookie/" + login + ".bin");
bf.Serialize(wstr, client.CookieContainer);
wstr.Close();
```

Загружаю при необходимости для следующих запросов с помощью:

```
var rstr = File.OpenRead(_path + "/Cookie/" + login + ".bin");
_client.CookieContainer = (CookieContainer)new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(rstr);
```

Сейчас появилась необходимость эти куки использовать в браузере, выбрал для себя библиотеку CefSharp, но не совсем понимаю как мне теперь туда их загрузить

Если есть какая-то библиотека которая использует CookieContainer и там можно добавить User-Agent и прокси - можно использовать ее, буду благодарен за подсказку.

P.S. Отправлять http запрос через CefSharp и получать/сохранять куки - не вариант.

Comment: Зачем вам вдруг понадобился браузер, если вы успешно работали через `RestClient`? Да и зачем он вам, если можно использовать стандартный `HttpClient`? Странный у вас выбор конечно...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ конечному пользователю может понадобится открыть сайт в браузере с куками которые использовались в http запросах для совершения некоторых действий вручную (да, все можно сделать через http, но так надо).

Comment: `BinaryFormatter` устарел. Чтобы достать куки из контейнера, можно использовать [вот такой изврат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1217351/373567) через рефлексию. Возможно появится нативный метод добычи всех кук из контейнера в .NET 6, но это пока маловероятно.