# Chrome driver отключение css / картинок / всё - кроме JS

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

Как на ChromeDriver отключить всё кроме JS ?

- Чтобы вообще ничего ничего не грузилось при загрузке страницы, только html и js

Пытался искать, не нашёл.

Из того что нашёл, для отключение CSS нужно расширение прикрутить.

А в дефолтных настройках только картинки.

```
        string defProfile = "profile.default_content_setting_values.";
        options.AddUserProfilePreference($"{defProfile}images", 2);
```

Comment: Зачем вам тогда селениум, если не собираетесь отображать страницы?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ немного парсинга, там где хочу применить, API нет, а через POST пройти не смог =( 
А прокси трафик кушают.

Comment: Наверно плохо пробовали, но не видя, чего вы хотите, вряд ли скажу, что полезного.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да, я помню, вы мозг в этом деле, а я не смог пока. Вот и интересуюсь как облегчить браузер

Comment: [Просто оставлю это здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1178026/373567), вдруг пригодится. А так без конкретного адреса и задачи невозможно сказать, как оптимальнее подъехать к ее решению. Но юзать хром ради JS движка - такое себе занятие. Есть кстати альтернатива - AngleSharp - этот пакет 2 в 1, и парсер и есть расширение AngleSharp.Js, чтобы скрипты на загруженной странице выполнялись.