# Использование Selenium C# с получением и отправкой данных JSON

Tags: c#, json, selenium

форумчане.

Пишу restApi, которое будет принимать JSON в качестве запроса от мобильных устройств, далее парсить сайт при помощи Selenium и отправлять ответ обратно на мобильный телефон в формате JSON.
В этом вопросе являюсь новичком, но нашёл информацию, что Selenium не поддерживает работу .Net Core.
Получится ли вообще такое реализовать при помощи Selenium, учитывая проблему поддержки .Net Core?

Selenium планирую использовать в связи с тем, что сайт блокирует обычные парсинги, а Selenium заявляет в документации, что способен создавать видимость обычного пользователя.

Благодарю за ответы.

Comment: Поиском по фразе "Selenium не поддерживает работу .Net Core" находится это: "В .NET Core, Selenium пока не поддерживается, что делает его сложным для проведения веб-тестов на передней панели. К счастью, вы можете ссылаться на пакеты, если вы добавите отдельный проект в свое решение, которое является C# Class Library указанной в .NET Framework." (Вот вам и решение) Если вы имеете ввиду какую-то другую проблему - уточните, какую именно вы имеете ввиду.

Comment: Selenium != парсинг, Selenium == тестирование!! Ну а так, [Релиз](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver) - поддержка `.NETStandard 2.0`, ну и [бета](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/4.0.0-beta2) - поддерживает .NETStandard 2.0 и 2.1, а также .NET5.

Comment: Selenium вообще не для парсинга сайтов, если что, а для автотестов. Это как на танке в магазин за хлебом. [Вот альтернатива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1178026/373567), как вариант. По поводу обхода всяких защит - учите протокол HTTP и всё что с ним связано.

Comment: Тут проблема не совсем в куках. Изначально парсер писали на php, там передавали куки через JSON и отправляли запрос. Все было прекрасно, пока сайт не заблокировал IP, где находится парсер.
Хотел использовать Selenium для обхода защиты от парсера.