# Компрессия и декомпрессия GZIP для методов POST и GET?

Tags: c#, http, post, get, gzip

Имеется код связи с определенным сайтом. Через него я получаю данные, которые в процессе успеваю поменять или доработать, а после эти измененные данные мною отправляются вновь на сайт. Все бы ничего, но сам процесс работы, его желательно ускорить, оптимизировать. И чтоб подобное сделать, мне нужно как-то реализовать компрессии gzip для POST метода и декомпрессии gzip для GET метода:

```
namespace SoftWARE
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Text;
 
    public class Connecter
    {
        public CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
        public string OriginUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OriginUrl"];
 
        public HttpWebRequest GetNewRequest(string targetUrl, CookieContainer SessionCookieContainer)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(targetUrl);
            request.CookieContainer = SessionCookieContainer;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            return request;
        }
 
        public HttpWebResponse MakeRequest(HttpWebRequest request, CookieContainer SessionCookieContainer, Dictionary<string, string> parameters = null, int TypeRequest = 0)
        {
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36 OPR/32.0.1948.25Accept: */*";
            request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            request.Proxy = new WebProxy();
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
            request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 100;
            ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri(this.OriginUrl));
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
            request.Headers["Origin"] = this.OriginUrl;
            if (TypeRequest == 1)
            {
                request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest";
            }
            if (TypeRequest == 2)
            {
                request.Headers["Upgrade-Insecure-Requests"] = "1";
            }
            request.CookieContainer = SessionCookieContainer;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            if (parameters != null)
            {
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                string s = "";
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in parameters)
                {
                    if (s.Length == 0)
                    {
                        s += $"{pair.Key}={pair.Value}";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        s += $"&{pair.Key}={pair.Value}";
                    }
                }
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
                using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                request.Method = "GET";
            }
            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            SessionCookieContainer.Add(response.Cookies);
            while (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Found)
            {
                response.Close();
                request = this.GetNewRequest(response.Headers["Location"], SessionCookieContainer);
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                SessionCookieContainer.Add(response.Cookies);
            }
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `HttpWebRequest` устарел, используйте `HttpClient`. [Важно! Мы не рекомендуем использовать `HttpWebRequest` для новой разработки. Вместо этого используйте `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` класс.](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=net-5.0#remarks)

Comment: Это интересно! А если не сложно конечно же, можно ли как-то подробно описать как именно эти изменения внести в этот код?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30314170/5045688

Comment: В .NET 6, который выйдет в ноябре, WebRequest и WebClient уже объявлены Obsolete. Так что да, используйте HttpClient.

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: И да и нет. За ответ спасибо, действительно многое стало ясным!
Почему же не совсем понял, сейчас теперь делаю/ переписываю другой Class на HttpClient, который и использует данные Сonnector( По сути, в программировании я почти профан, но так как появилась надобность острая, приходится делать!)
Т.е. если class. Connecter был самым главным, центральным, то то что делаю сейчас, оно уже конкретно обрабатывает запросы на второстепенные ссылки, также относящиеся к OriginalUrl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HttpWebRequest` устарел, используйте `HttpClient`.

[Документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=net-5.0#remarks):

> Важно! Мы не рекомендуем использовать `HttpWebRequest` для новой разработки. Вместо этого используйте `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` класс.

Вот, переписал ваш код под `HttpClient`, старался максимально сохранить вашу логику.

```cs
public class Connecter
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    public string OriginUrl { get; }
    public CookieContainer Cookies { get; }

    public Connecter(CookieContainer cookies = null)
    {
        OriginUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OriginUrl"];
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
        { 
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.All // включение поддержки компрессии Content-Encoding: gzip, defalte, br - добавлять заголовок вручную не нужно
            // здесь можно задать еще кучу всяких парамемтров подключения
        }; 
        if (cookies != null)
            handler.CookieContainer = cookies;
        Cookies = handler.CookieContainer;
        _client = new HttpClient(handler)
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(OriginUrl),
            //DefaultRequestVersion = HttpVersion.Version20 // поддержка HTTP/2 доступна в .NET Core 3.1, .NET 5 и новее
        };
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36 OPR/32.0.1948.25");
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.ParseAdd("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    }

    public Task<string> GetAsync(string url)
    {
        return _client.GetStringAsync(url); 
    }

    public async Task<string> PostFormAsync(string url, Dictionary<string, string> parameters, int TypeRequest = 0)
    {
        using HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url)
        { 
            Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters) 
        };
        request.Headers.Add("Origin", OriginUrl);
        if (TypeRequest == 1)
        {
            request.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        }
        if (TypeRequest == 2)
        {
            request.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
        }
        using HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Смысл включения компрессии в том, что вы сообщаете серверу, что поддерживаете декомпрессию. Сервер если пожелает, сожмет свой ответ. `HttpClient` распакует ответ автоматически.

С куками `HttpClient` работает как браузер, то есть каждый последующий запрос учитывает куки добавленные сервером в предыдущем запросе. То есть за пределами этого класса вы можете сохранять и загружать куки, например при запуске и завершении приложения.

Лишние настройки протокола я выкинул, так как они либо не на что не влияют, либо совпадают с настройками по умолчанию.

Использовать это вот так.

К примеру, есть ссылка `https://my.api/post_method` и `https://my.api/get_method`. В этом случе `OriginUrl` должен быть `https://my.api/`, а запросы отправлять нужно вот так.

```cs
string getResponseText = await connecter.GetAsync("get_method");
string postResponseText = await connecter.PostFormAsync("post_method", data, 1);
```

- Если не понятно, что такое `async/await`, почитайте [Асинхронное Программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).
- Еще пример по теме [Работа с Cookie в HttpClient для парсинга с авторизацией](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1178026/373567)

Еще у вас была синтаксическая ошибка в `UserAgent`, я исправил. Ну и само собой эта конструкция будет работать быстрее, а в .NET Core/.NET 5 - вообще быстро, потому что там используется новый HTTP движок `SocketsHttpHandler`, в .NET Framework 4.x используется старый движок, поэтому ощутимого прироста скорости может не произойти.