# Сохранение логина при повторной авторизации WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть вот такое вот окошко

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу по нажатию на `Запомнить` сохранить логин. Как это лучше сделать? Сохранить в файл какой-нибудь? А если его удалят?

Comment: А как по вашему работает авторизация в браузере? Очищение localstorage/cookie точно также приведет к повторному входу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К примеру, пусть ваш проект будет называться `MyLoginSaver`.

#### Реестр

Быть может не самое удачное решение, но самое удобное, и возможно пригодится вам для других целей - хранить в реестре Windows.

Подключите неймпейс

```cs
using Microsoft.Win32;
```

И заведите 2 метода.

```cs
private static readonly string registryPath =
    Path.Combine(Registry.CurrentUser.Name, "Software", "MyLoginSaver");

private static string GetRegistryKey(string key)
{
    return (string)Registry.GetValue(registryPath, key, string.Empty);
}

private static void SetRegistryKey(string key, string value)
{
    Registry.SetValue(registryPath, key, value, RegistryValueKind.String);
}
```

Использовать это просто.

```cs
SetRegistryKey("Login", Login);
```

```cs
Login = GetRegistryKey("Login");
```

А не самое удачное решение потому, что данные, вводимые пользователем не принято сохранять в реестр. В реестр принято сохранять только данные, полученные програмным способом, например координаты и размер окна, какие-то настройки приложения, полученные из чекбоксов или других контролов, где пользователю не разрешен произвольный ввод данных.

Смягчить обстановку может принудительное ограничение максимальной длины логина в текстбоксе.

```xml
<TextBox Text="{Binding Login}" MaxLength="50" />
```

Тогда у пользователя хотя-бы не будет возможности вставить в него например 5 мегабайт текста и крашнуть приложение, которое попытается записать в реестр эту кучу данных.

---

#### Файл

Второй, и наверное более гибкий вариант - хранить в файле.

```cs
private static readonly string appData =
    Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "MyLoginSaver");
```

Это значит путь `%APPDATA%\MyLoginSaver` или если полностью, то `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\MyLoginSaver`.

Ну и пишите в эту папку нужные файлы.

```cs
public class MySettings
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
}
```

Записать

```cs
MySettings settings = new MySettings { Login = "admin" };
string settingsText = JsonSerializer.Serialize(settings);
File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(appData, "settings.json"), settingsText);
```

Прочитать

```cs
string settingsText = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(appData, "settings.json"));
MySettings settings = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(settingsText);
```

Comment: Можно немножечко добавить безопасности: пусть программа содержит некую соль (вшитый const-ключ шифрования), программа при первом запуске генерирует случайный открытый ключ и помещает его в реестр, затем, когда надо шифровать/дешифровать файл с логином/паролем - применяет соль к ключу в реестре, тем самым получая закрытый ключ, и уже этим ключом шифрует/дешифрует файл. PS я в шифровании почти полный ноль, как это правильней сделать. Но хотя бы это лучше, чем ничего, когда надо в информационную безопасность.

Comment: @Blackmeser оторвитесь немного от нуля :) и поизучайте, что такое Windows DPAPI (класс `ProtectedData`), там все очень просто, он заменяет все что вы описали однострочником без необходимости выдумывать и хранить ключ. Но шифровать данные, которые не содержат конфиденциальной информации (например куки браузера), смысла примерно никакого. [Вот пример хранения данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1178026/373567), шифрованных с помощью AES, прямо рядом с ключом, зашифрованным DPAPI. Но можно вообще без AES обойтись.