# Создание новых записей в ComboBox и их сохранение

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть форма с ComboBox, TextBox и кнопкой. В TextBox делаем запись и с помощью кнопки передаем текст в ComboBox.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу сделать сохранение данных в ComboBox. Чтобы при следующем запуске у нас остались ранее записанные марки. Я знаю что можно сделать через бд или текстовый файл, но хотелось бы обойтись без них.

Comment: Это winforms? Пожалуйста уточните необходимые детали, отредактируйте вопрос. К тегу `обработка-данных` вопрос как именно относится?

Comment: Да, это winforms, тег обработка-данных был добавлен так как в программе идет работа с данными.

Comment: Вы не поверите, но совершенно в любой программе есть работа с данными.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы сохранить данные в ComboBox я использовал Settings.settings.
В файле Settings.settings имя "userText1" имеет тип "string", а "userComboBox" имеет тип "System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection".

```
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        StringCollection coll = Properties.Settings.Default.userComboBox;
        foreach (var item in coll)
            markaComboBox.Items.Add(item);
    }

    private void NewMarkaButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        markaComboBox.Items.Add(newMarkaTextBox.Text);

        Properties.Settings.Default.userText1 = newMarkaTextBox.Text;

        StringCollection coll = new StringCollection();
        coll.AddRange(markaComboBox.Items.Cast<string>().ToArray());
        Properties.Settings.Default.userComboBox = coll;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

Метод "MainForm" позволяет загрузить данные из userComboBox в markaComboBox.

Метод "NewMarkaButton_Click" создает запись в ComboBox'e и сохраняет изменения.

https://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread2317217.html

Comment: `StringCollection` - это что-то очень древнее, так уже не пишет никто давно. Перепишите на `List<string>`.

Comment: Поизучал вопрос, вы используете `Settings` не по назначению. `Settings` используется для хранения настроек приложения, то есть практически фиксированного набора данных. Оно просто не предназначено для сохранения пользовательской информации. [Параметры приложения для Windows Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/application-settings-for-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: Если использовать списки, то тогда не обойтись без файла, в котором хранятся значения нужные для ComboBox. Или я что-то не верно понял?

Comment: Окей, пусть эта `StringCollection` живет, если речь о `Settings` и объехать это никак. Microsoft уже давно сознались, что это костыли и рано или поздно специализированные коллекции будут уничтожены в пользу обобщенных. Вот, почитайте еще [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1348911/373567), вдруг пригодится.

Comment: Спасибо. Попытаюсь сделать через хранение записей в файле.