# Что лучше использовать для сохранения настроек: Json или реестр?

Tags: c#, winforms

Пишу программу на `win forms`, там есть небольшие настройки, их нужно будет инициализировать при старте программы (если данные есть), и сохранить, когда пользователь сделает нужные действия и нажмёт `Save`.

ПЫ.СЫ: я пытался подключить `System.Text.Json` директиву не находит :)

Comment: Все в программе, вся логика, расположение и др. зависит всегда от одного, **потребностей**, если программа портативная, простая утилитка, то зачем ей, к примеру лезть в реестр или другие системные вещи? Достаточно ведь сохранить данные в одном файлике рядом с .exe и все. Если же программа полноценная, с установщиком, с кучей библиотек и прочим, она располагается в `Programm Files`, программа под разных пользователей OS имеет свои настройки, то логично будет все это хранить в реестре, верно? Ну а если программа вовсе сетевая, работа с сервером, то тут наверно логичней хранить данные в базе.

Comment: `я пытался подключить System.Text.Json директиву не находит` -  "из коробки" он доступен **только** в проектах `5, 6, Core 3.0, Core 3.1`, для .NET Framework последних версий он располагается в виде [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json) пакета. Для старых .Framework его нет.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1348911/373567

Comment: Предлагаю хранить json в реестре в двоичном или многостроковом параметре:)

Comment: @Sergey смешная шутка, оценил

Comment: "что лучше использовать для еды: тарелку или салат?" вилку!