# Помогите научить программу работать с cookie и подключаться через прокси

Tags: python, c#, proxy

Пишу бота для сайта, необходимо, чтобы он перед выполнением написаного задания подключался к индивидуальным прокси (брал их из заданного тхт файла, в котором указаны доступы прокси)
в идеале решение для C# Visual Studio

Comment: Что именно не получается? Текстовый файл прочитать?

Comment: нет, у меня пока программа умеет только запускать браузер и заходить на сайт от моего же интернета, а хотелось бы прописать код на кнопку в c# чтобы при нажатии на эту кнопку выбираешь тхт файл с списком проксями и программа заходит уже на сайт из под прокси

Comment: Прокси надо прописать в браузере? На пайтоне используйте селениум.

Comment: Прокси уже прописаны в тхт файле, а использовались чтобы они в браузере да, который запускает написанная мной программа

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730306/setting-a-proxy-for-chrome-driver-in-selenium

Comment: Зависит от хоста, но в 99,9% случаев для роБОТизации доступа к хосту, браузер не нужен. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1178026/373567