# C# Скачать файл с учетом авторизации

Tags: c#, login

Доброе время суток,
помогите пожалуйста имеется ссылка https://target.com/xxx.zip прежде чем скачать данный файл нужно авторизоваться, собственно и вопрос как на консольке СиШарпа написать программу которая будет автоматически входить в учетку и скачивать данный файл. (П.С. Сыылка на файл всегда статично)
Не пинать я новичок (

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1178026/373567