# Пост-запросом изменить аватар в Steam C#

Tags: c#, изображения, post, steam

привет всем.

Я пытаюсь одним пост-запросом изменить аватар в Steam.

Так должен выглядеть запрос:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот такой получается у меня:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Net;
 
namespace Test
{
    class TestProgram
    {
        static readonly CookieContainer container = new CookieContainer();
        static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.All,
            CookieContainer = container
        });
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Image newImage = Image.FromFile(@"D:\Bot files\images\photo_2022-01-24_13-01-11.jpg");
            ImageConverter _imageConverter = new ImageConverter();
            byte[] paramFileStream = (byte[])_imageConverter.ConvertTo(newImage, typeof(byte[]));
 
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Referer", "https://steamcommunity.com/id/spaden2k/edit/avatar");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Origin", "https://steamcommunity.com");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Host", "steamcommunity.com");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Sec-Fetch-Dest", "empty");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "cors");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Sec-Fetch-Site", "same-origin");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
 
            var cookies = new Cookie("sessionid", "тут данные", "/", "steamcommunity.com");
            container.Add(cookies);
            cookies = new Cookie("_ga", "тут данные", "/", "steamcommunity.com");
            container.Add(cookies);
            cookies = new Cookie("_gid", "тут данные", "/", "steamcommunity.com");
            container.Add(cookies);
            cookies = new Cookie("steamLoginSecure", "тут данные", "/", "steamcommunity.com");
            container.Add(cookies);
            cookies = new Cookie("browserid", "тут данные", "/", "steamcommunity.com");
            container.Add(cookies);
            cookies = new Cookie("steamMachineAuth76561198820241567", "тут данные", "/", "steamcommunity.com");
            container.Add(cookies);
            cookies = new Cookie("steamRememberLogin", "тут данные", "/", "steamcommunity.com");
            container.Add(cookies);
 
            var streamImg = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(paramFileStream));
                streamImg.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"avatar\"; filename=\"blob\"");
                streamImg.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "image/png");
 
 
                var formContent = new MultipartFormDataContent
                {
                    {streamImg,"avatar","blob"},
                };
 
                var response = client.PostAsync("https://steamcommunity.com/actions/FileUploader/", formContent).Result;
 
            
            Console.ReadKey();
 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `_ga` и `_gid` куки - это Google аналитика, можете их выбросить, они не относятся к Steam, другими словами это отслеживающий вас мусор. Транспортный заголовок `Connection` тоже ни к чему, его `HttpClient` сам добавит, если посчитает нужным, и скорее всего он так и сделает. А вот `User-Agent` я бы добавил `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0");`.

Comment: @aepot Спасибо за ответ! И ещё, у меня вопрос: как я могу добавить ещё несколько параметров в мультипарт? Т.е. там ещё нужно указать айди, тип и т.д.

Comment: Так добавьте еще стинг-контентов, как я указывал в прошлом ответе `{ streamImg, stringContent1, stringContent2,... }`. Если ответ был полезен, вы можете принять его галочкой.

Comment: @aepot Ещё раз, огромное спасибо, как всегда выручаете! Я так и делал, добавлял StringContent, но результата не было, стоило только поменять куки на более актуальные и тут же сработало! 

Я так заметил, что у меня чаще ошибки происходят из-за куков, поэтому я сделал вход в стим с сохранением куков, теперь они будут только актуальные!

Comment: `HttpClient` правильно с куками работает, если что. То есть если в процессе работы ему от сервера приходят куки, он вносит их в контейнер. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1178026/373567

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На скрине сигнатура PNG файла, а в коде вы JPEG грузите. Конечно визуально бинарник PNG и JPEG отличаются. То есть вам либо надо путь поменять на PNG картинку, либо MIME type на `image/jpeg`. И не используйте `.Result`, используйте `await` как я вам показывал.

Прочитать картинку в массив байт можно вот так

```
byte[] bytes = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync("image.png");
```

А вы чего-то намудрили.

А лучше вообще открыть его в поток и отдать в контент. Итого получится:

```
using var fs = File.OpenRead("image.png");
var streamImg = new StreamContent(fs);
streamImg.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data") { Name = "avatar", FileName = "blob" };
streamImg.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
var formContent = new MultipartFormDataContent
{
    streamImg
};
```

Как определить MIME type картинки по расширению файла, можно подглядеть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1029740/12888024).

Если хочется по содержимому, то можно как-то так с использованием GDI+

```
using Image bmp = Image.FromFile("image.png");
string imgType = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
    .FirstOrDefault(codec => codec.FormatID == bmp.RawFormat.Guid)?.MimeType ?? "application/unknown";
// выдаст "image/png"
```