# Выполнения всех скриптов javascript в httpClient c#

Tags: javascript, c#, httpclient

Я очень долго хочу и ищу способы узнать как выполнять скрипты `javascript`.
Т.е делаю запрос на сайт, и мне в ответ должен прийти уже вся html страница где например подгрузилесь данные с помощи `ajax`, или просто выполнились скрипты.

Делаю я парсер сайтов, и пользователь сам должен ввести ссылку на сайт, если нужно то и куки.
Но беда в том что многие сайты используют `javascript`.

Я знаю что через **httpWebRequest**, **httpClient**, не возможно выполнить `javascript`.
Я пробовал **webBrowser**, он хоть и возвращает уже страницу с выполненным `javascript`, но я понятие не имею как передавать туда куки, вроде этого нельзя сделать.

Использовать **Selenium** мне не нужно, потому что все таки мне просто нужно взять полностью всю страницу html, и **selenium** я как знаю слишком медленный.
Пожалуйста! Есть ли способы сделать это? Может как то полученный html текст с **httpClient** как то обрабатывать и выполнять `javascript`? Но опять же, я думаю что некоторые `ajax` запросы используют куки, (хотя это мне не очень волнует)

Comment: Есть пакет `WebView2` (Edge) и парсер AngleSharp, для него есть JS модуль, который можно установить отдельно. `WebBrowser` (IE 11) и `HttpWebRequest` - давно устаревшие классы. А `HttpClient` - это транспорт, он просто грузит файлы и страницы с сервера. Зачастую JS выполнять не нужно, те же JS скрипты отправляют такие же HTTP запросы на сервер, можно отловить эти запросы и сымитировать в принципе не выполняя никаких скриптов. Изучайте сетевые логи браузера.

Comment: @aepot спасибо за подсказки. Вы пишите что зачастую js выполнять не нужно. Я не понял этого.
Вы имеете ввиду что нужно отловить запросы которые возвращают данные которые мне нужны? Или что?

Comment: Да, верно, отловить запросы.

Comment: @aepot хорошо. Это вроде бы не проблематично, если только некоторые запросы не требуют куки.
Но такой подход мне в любом случаи не подойдет! Все таки я пользовался одним парсером, ему задаешь ссылку на сайт, и в настройках указываешь ему что парсить, и он парсить и парсит javascript и очень шустро. Хочу сделать так-же, и к сожалению я думаю пользователь не очень захочет анализировать запросы что бы потом спарсить информацию. Спасибо все таки за ответ!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553 Если делаете "универсальное" решение, то это бред, каждый сайт УНИКАЛЕН, любому пользователю так или иначе надо будет анализировать сайт, смотреть что и как он делает и эмулировать его работу программно.

Comment: Если бы можно было написать что-то универсальное, уже кто-нибудь давно написал. Вот [пример с куками](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1217351/373567).