# Как парсить веб-сайт с предварительной авторизацией при помощи C# для веб-сайта на ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, парсер, asp.net

Разрабатываю сайт на ASP.NET, который должен собирать и отображать информацию с нескольких сайтов. На данных сайтах мне нужен только HTML код, но чтобы его получить, нужно каким-то образом предварительно авторизоваться. Сайт не имеет никакого API. Программно авторизация происходит тяжело.
Может быть можно каким-то образом взаимодействовать с веб-страницей(ввод и отправка данных) по типу Selenium, но чтобы это можно было каким-то образом уместить в веб-сайте на ASP.NET?
Какие есть способы выполнения авторизации в таком случае?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1178026/373567

Comment: Спасибо большое!