# HttpClient, обновление cookie

Tags: c#, cookie, httpclient

Я отправляю запросы в steam предварительно добавив куки из авторизации, один из куки - steamLoginSecure периодически меняется. И вот в очередной запрос steam прислал новый steamLoginSecure. Но проблема в том что старый не удаляется, и в следующем запросе отправляется 2 steamLoginSecure, старый и новый. [image]

Добавлялись куки так:

```
foreach (var item in cookie_diction)
{
   cookie.Add(new Cookie(item.Key, item.Value, "/", ".steamcommunity.com"));
   cookie.Add(new Cookie(item.Key, item.Value, "/", ".steampowered.com"));
}

httpClientHandler.CookieContainer = cookie;
client = new HttpClient(handler: httpClientHandler, disposeHandler: true);
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1178026/373567 вам не нужно ничего делать с куками в `HttpClient`, он сам ведет себя так же как браузер, все что нужно это перед началом работы загрузить куки в контейнер, а после окончания работы сохранить их оттуда. В процессе запросов вся работа с куками будет происходить автоматически.

Comment: @aepot Но всё же почему-то я наблюдаю, в следующем запросе 2 отправленных cookie со старым и новым значением, хотя он должен удалять старое значение.

Comment: Если дата `expires=` в прошлом, значит кука устаревшая, любой адекватный сервер должен ее игнорить, а браузер удалять. То есть ответ от сервера с истекшей кукой может значить удаление этой куки. Оно вообще влияет на работу с сервером? Если нет, то и вашего внимания оно тоже не стоит.

Comment: На ответ сервера это вроде как не повлияло, завтра проверю это наверняка, и попробую вытащить куки из клиента, надеюсь там не будет старого значения.