# Как установить куки?

Tags: c#, selenium

Пробую так:
сохраняю данные аккаунта в bin файл, затем читаю с него информацию.
Чтение кук:

```
// Сохраняем куки
        CookieContainer cookieCont = new CookieContainer();
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.wildberries.ru");
        request.CookieContainer = cookieCont;

        // Записываем куки в файл
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (Stream stream = new FileStream(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\ProfCookie\" + Variables.Name+Variables.Surname + ".bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            formatter.Serialize(stream, cookieCont);
            stream.Close();
        }
```

запись кук:

```
Variables.profilesList = Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\ProfCookie").ToList();
        string loneProfile = Variables.profilesList[0];
        Variables.profilesList.RemoveAt(0);
        Variables.profilesList.Add(loneProfile);
        Console.WriteLine($"Берем профиль - {loneProfile}");

        //Читаем куки из файла:
        try //заключаем в блок try, поскольку при открытии файла может возникнуть исключение(например, если файл открыт другой программой для монопольного доступа и т.д...)
        {
            using (Stream stream = new FileStream(loneProfile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                try //заключаем в блок try, поскольку во время десериализации может возникнуть иключение (если в указанном файле хранится не правильно сериализованные куки или их там вообще нет)
                {
                    cookieCont = (CookieContainer)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                }
                stream.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
```

при этом файл читается, но куки не применяются. Что могу не так делать?

Comment: `HttpWebRequest` устарел, когда я еще под стол пешком ходил, и `BinaryFormatter` тоже. Вы скопировали очень старый дореволюционный код. Вот пример посвежее https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1178026/373567

Comment: Спасибо за помощь