# C# Вместимость CookieContainer

Tags: c#, cookie

Всем привет, подскажите сколько записей может хранить CookiesContainer, например у библиотеки leaf.xnet вместимость хранилища 300 записей. Интересует объем хранения CookiesContainer

Comment: Если кратко, то очень много, а вам сколько надо? 2147483647 хватит? Точное значение зависит от распределения кук по доменам.

Comment: @aepot допустим мне нужно 150 доменов. Хранилище вместить в себя столько? Или лучше с файла подтягивать нужные домены?

Comment: Так, стоп, что такое `CookiesContainer`? Я думал, что вы про `CookieContainer`

Comment: @aepot я опечатался вы верно подумали про CookieContainer, по ответу сами cokie можно хранить много но почему то в библиотеке https://github.com/csharp-leaf/Leaf.xNet/blob/master/Leaf.xNet/~Http/CookieStorage.cs можно хранить максимум 300

Comment: @aepot можно же переопределить класс работы библиотеки на CookieContainer чтобы увеличить лимит?

Comment: Можно выбросить либу и [писать на чистом дотнете](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1178026/373567).

Comment: @aepot согласен, в целом можно написать обёртку либу и пользоваться в удовольствие, что ещё лучше)