# System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a closed Stream.' при отправке Post запроса

Tags: c#, xamarin

Накидал я небольшую программу в консоли, отправляющую Post запрос на сайт.

```
private static void Main()
{
    SendPostAsync();
}

static async void SendPostAsync()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    var body = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"login", "97328"},
    {"pass", "97328"},
};

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(body);

    content.Headers.Add("Cookie", new string[]
        {
        "PHPSESSID=jn81op7nnt8r29r4qfb4erhnu4",
        "secure=1"
        });

    await client.PostAsync(@"https://chgu.org/", content);
    await client.PostAsync(@"https://chgu.org/?role=136664", content);

    var response = await client.GetAsync(@"https://chgu.org/user/friends");
}
```

Все работает отлично. Ошибок нет. Затем создал проект Xamarin, вставил туда этот же метод и вызвал его.

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnStart()
{
    SendPostAsync();
}
```

И на те! `System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a closed Stream.'`
Немного погуглив выяснил что ошибка возникает при попытке обращения к "закрытому" потоку.
[Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934585/memorystream-cannot-access-a-closed-stream) чувак написал использовать `MemoryStream` однако я так и не понял как его использовать в моем случае. Также пробовал использовать:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(SendPostAsync);
thread.Start();
```

Увы тоже не помогло. В итоге, так и не сумев решить проблему самостоятельно пишу вам, господа. За ранее спасибо.

Comment: А что этот код должен сделать то? Почему вы отправляете пост и не чистаете ответ? Что вы хотите получить из гета? Почему поста 2?

Comment: @aepot Пытался спарсить сайт с авторизацией. Первые 2 Post запроса служат для авторизации на сайте, чтобы тут: `var response = await client.GetAsync(@"https://chgu.org/user/friends");` получить html и дальше работать с ним.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так должно быть, если ничего в логике не менять

```
private static async Task Main()
{
    try
    {
        await SendPostAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}

private static readonly HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

static async Task SendPostAsync()
{
    // это запрос проинициализирует куки сайта, но вряд-ли это необходимо
    string mainPage = await client.GetAsync("https://chgu.org/");
    
    var body = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"login", "97328"},
        {"pass", "97328"},
    };
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(body);

    //PHPSESSID вам точно не нужна, она уже в контейнер легла сама после первого GET запроса.
    //Для доступа к кукам используйте handler.CookieContainer
    
    using (var response = await client.PostAsync("https://chgu.org/?role=136664", content))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"POST Result: {(int)response.StatusCode} {response.ReasonPhrase}");
        string postResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(postResult);
    }

    string html = await client.GetStringAsync(@"https://chgu.org/user/friends");
}
```

[Работа с Cookie в HttpClient для парсинга с авторизацией](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1178026/373567)

P.S. У вас ничего не получится, там капча защищает сайт.