# Сервер не дает запрос

Tags: c#, httpclient

Имею рабочий код с использованием Webclient'а

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
        
        wc.Headers["Cookie"] = (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String("")));
        string Cookie = (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String("")));
        string server = (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String("")));
        string useragent = (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String("")));
        string php = (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String("")));

        byte[] data = wc.DownloadData(server + php);
```

Он работает. Если смотреть запросы фидлера, то возвращает гет и пост запросы

Этот код

```
                HttpClient remote = new HttpClient();

            string useragent = ("Mozilla/6.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;Trident / 7.0; rv: 11.0) like Gecko");
            string server = ("http://192.168.31.129");
            string delimiter2 = (":");
            string cookie = ("");
            string php = ("");
            string port = ("");
            string delimiter = ("/");
            

            var BaseAddress = new Uri(server + delimiter2 + port);
            remote.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

            try
            {
                remote.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", useragent);
                var response1 = await remote.GetAsync(BaseAddress);
                var responseText = await response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            catch { }

            var content = "text/html;charset=utf-8";
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                Content = new StringContent(content)
            };
            response.Content.Headers.Add(@"Content-Length", content.Length.ToString());


            {
                using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { UseCookies = false })
                using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = BaseAddress })

                {
                    var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, BaseAddress + php);
                    message.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookie);
                    var result = await client.SendAsync(message);
                    result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                }
            }


                byte[] data = await remote.GetByteArrayAsync(BaseAddress + php);
```

В дебаге выдает "Код состояния ответа не указывает на успешное выполнение: 404 (NOT FOUND)."
Хотя передается юзерагент и сессия авторизации, но коннекта нет:(
Ломаю голову уже неделю. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста

Comment: вот пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1178026/373567, кучу лишней работы делаете, что я даже не смог понять, что должно в итоге получиться. Зачем-то 2 клиента, зачем-то куки в заголовки пихаете в то время как есть для них специальный контейнер. Зачем-то Content-Length прописываете, да еще и неверным значением. Длина контента - это в байтах кодировки UTF-8, а не в символах. Не надо ее прописывать, она автоматом пропишется правильная. При чем тут `HttpResponseMessage` вообще непонятно, вы это никак далее не используете.

Comment: С вариантом куки контейнера "Код состояния ответа не указывает на успешное выполнение: 405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED)"

Comment: Я вообще убрал куку с сервера и и юзер агент как требуемые при авторизации. Но ловлю 405

Comment: 405 обычно означает что там где можно только GET, вы отправили POST или наоборот.