# Как парсить данные со страницы, которую нужно обновить после загрузки, что бы увидеть содержимое?

Tags: c#, html, веб-скрейпинг

Есть html страница, с которой необходимо спарсить данные. При открытии её в браузере открывается пустой бланк, а при обновлении, добавляются данные.
я использую C#, HtmlAgillityPack

я думаю, что при запросе нужно указать какой либо параметр.

вот ссылка на страницу http://colled.beget.tech/

Comment: Возможно страница выставляет куки https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1178026/373567