# Отправка данных из формы на сайте из программы на пк

Tags: python, c#

Всем привет, интересует такая задача:
Я хочу сделать прогу, которая будет получать доступ к сайту, заполнять форму, и отправлять форму (p.s. я не пытаюсь никого взломать, это было бы глупо с учетом максимально-возможного кол-ва паролей)
Но я не понимаю каким образом подключаться к сайту из программы, находить там форму, осуществлять отправку, и после перезагрузки сайта делать те же действия еще раз.
Прошу подсказать с решением задачи на языках C#/python

Comment: Нет такого понятия "подключиться". Любой сайт работает по принципу отправки конкретных запросов на конкретный адрес. Ваша задача, отловить этот запрос, разобрать его, а потом просто отправить его через `HttpClient` (если C#), отсылая все нужные заголовки, тело и т.д. Начните [с этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553). Вам тут еще могут начать советовать селениум - советую сразу отказаться, ибо это как ехать на танке в магазин через дорогу..., да порой легче, но лучше понимать как устроены запросы, это надежней и качественней.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1178026/373567