HttpWebRequest не отправляет Header и Content. BadRequest
Метод отправляет Post запрос на сайт Wb для добавления его в корзину.
Код:
 CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
 cookieContainer.Add(new Cookie("_wbauid", "5..4", "/", "www.wildberries.by"));

 var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://cart-storage-api.wildberries.ru/api/basket/sync?ts=1..2&device_id=global-site");
 httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
 httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
 httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
 httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
 httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36";
 httpWebRequest.Host = "cart-storage-api.wildberries.ru:443";

 httpWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
 httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer ..");

 using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
 {
     string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
     {
         cod_1s = 45387309,
         chrt_id = 8..1,
         quantity = 1,
         op_type = 1,
         client_ts = 1..7,
         inListIndex = 2,
         tailObject = new
         {
             loc = "",
             loc_way = "IG",
             sort = "",
             terms = new { }
         }
     }, Formatting.Indented);

     streamWriter.Write(json);
 }

 var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

Приходит ответ BadRequest. Через Postman все нормально отправляется и приходит ответ.
Запрос из Postman в Fiddler

Запрос HttpWebRequest в Fiddler


в чем проблема
Я решил подгрузить все данные из HttpWebRequest  в postman итог все работает
сделал все точно также
единственный параметр который не из HttpWebRequest то это PostmanToken
все


HttpWebRequest является устаревшим в C#, его не стоит использовать для отправки запросов. Заменой ему является HttpClient. 2. CONNECT запросы смотреть не лучшая затея, смотрите сами POST запросы, которые идут после подключения. 3. Меня смущает как вы формируете JSON, вы уверены, что на выходе у вас именно тот объект, которые требуется? Советую создать классы... P.S. С HttpClient ваш код будет примерно следующим: var resp = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync("https://...", new {...});, ну и авторизация _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = ..;, все остальное сделает клиент сам


Версия .NET какая? А вообще раз реакция сервера разная, значит и запросы разные. Так как вы показываете их не целиком, то их невозмодно толком сравнить. И да, HttpWebRequest мёртв, ваш код устарел лет на 10, возможно прична в этом. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1217351/373567
