Как спарсить любой сайт с помощью си шарп и дополнительных библиотек без апи и Selenium?
Как можно создать парсер который может парсить сайт , не используя апи и selenium? Ну тоесть такой парсер, который абсолютно любой сайт смог бы спарсить. Ну например в каких-то местах сайта есть текст номер 1 и текст номер 2. И парсер должен в процессе программы показать информацию первого текста, и информацию второго.

задача не совсем ясна. Если у сайта нет API, и вы не хотите прибегать к таким тяжеловесам как Selenium, то вы можете парсить HTML с помощью AngleSharp, например, и с помощью XPATH/CSS-селекторов находить нужные данные

Не существует и не будет существовать универсальных способов, включая селениум, это не универсальный способ, и даже больше, это не способ парсинга, это способ тестирования СВОЕГО сайта. Так что, не ленитесь и ищите под каждый сайт свой подход и пишите свой, уникальный парсер, без селениумов и прочего, простыми POST/GET запросами, достаточно простого HttpClient.

Как спарсить любой сайт?

Вот, как с HttpClient парсить?

Все зависит от сайта. Вот представьте задачу - перенести текст с носителя в электронный вид, как решите? Наверно, сначала вы поинтересуетесь "а что это за носитель?", вам в ответ "бумажный", вы дальше наверно поинтересуетесь "в каком он состоянии?", вам скажут "он очень древний", ну и др. наводящие вопросы, которые позволят вам собрать тот инструментарий, который позволит решить данную задачу. Заметьте, универсального решения просто быть не может, ибо носители разные, с разным состоянием, где условный "скан" документа может повредить условный древний манускрипт.

Вот с сайтами тоже самое, они все написаны по разному, где одни хранят данные в HTML, другие пустую страницу в которую подгружаются данные при помощи JS, сами эти данные могут получаться как "скрытыми API" запросами, самим JS, а может и вовсе Соккет. Также защита, один сайт дает данные сразу, а другой имеет уйму механизмов, которые мешают забрать нужное (у вас вон по вопросам вижу, что проблема с ютубом была, скорей всего из-за защиты, ибо гугл очень любит пихать палки  колеса). Вот поэтому универсального решения быть не может.

Так что, начните с изучения конкретного ресурса. Вот вам несколько примеров: как работать с запросами я писал тут, а тут я писал небольшую инструкцию по работе с конкретным сайтом, ну а вот я автоматизировал авторизацию на яндексе, а тут сайт с вебсоккетами. Как видите, решения везде разные. Изучайте, подбирайте под конкретный сайт, пробуйте, если не получится, задавайте тут вопросы.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1217351/373567 вот

дада я так и понял что там защита на ютюбе была.    Сделаю как вы сказали

aepot спасибо, мучался иногда с этим
